# Find text using regex but with similarity

Tags: java, regex

I recognized text list from different PDF documents. Now I need to extract some values from each of these texts using regular expressions. Some of my patterns is like that:

```
some text[ -]?(.+)[ ,-]+some other text
```

But the problem is that, after recognizing some of the letters can be wrong (`"0"` instead of `"O"`, `"I"` instead of `"l"` and etc.). That's why my pattern doesn't match it.

I want to use something like jaro-winkler or levenshtein similarity applied with regex so that I can then extract `MY_VALUE` from texts like `s0me text MY_VALUE, some otner text`.

I know it seems fantastic. But maybe this problem has a solution.

*Btw, I'm using Java, but can accept solutions in other languages*

Comment: Maybe try something like `s[0oO]me [0oO]t[hn]er text` ?

Comment: @HaoWu not so simple). 0-O and I-L are given for examples. In real situation there are too many combinations to cover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module in python, you can use fuzzy matching. The following regex allows for up to 2 errors in each phrase. You can use far more sophisticated error testing (for insertions, substitutions and deletions), see the linked documentation for details.

```py
import regex

txt = 's0me text MY_VALUE, some otner text'
pattern = regex.compile(r'(?:some text){e<=2}[ -]?(.+?)[ ,-]+(?:some other text){e<=2}')

m = pattern.search(txt)
if m is not None:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
MY_VALUE
```

Comment: Nice solution with fuzzy matching

Comment: yes, it works for Python. But in Java I could find alternative for {e<=2}

Comment: @Si7ius as far as I know the python regex library is the only one that supports this. You did say in the question that you could accept answers in other languages, that's why I posted this.

Comment: @Nick no problem) it is very good solution. At first I wanted to know is there any solutions. Now I'm just trying to find java alternative to your solution. Otherwise I just use python solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"

    "github.com/agnivade/levenshtein"
)

func findClosestMatch(text string, candidates []string, threshold int) (string, bool) {
    for _, candidate := range candidates {
        if levenshtein.ComputeDistance(strings.ToLower(text), strings.ToLower(candidate)) <= threshold {
            return candidate, true
        }
    }
    return "", false
}

func findMatches(text string, threshold int) []string {
    // Broad regex to capture potential matches
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(some\s*\w*\s*text\s*)([^,]+)`)
    potentialMatches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)

    var validMatches []string
    expectedPattern := "some text" // The pattern we expect to find

    for _, match := range potentialMatches {
        // Check if the first part of the match is close to our expected pattern
        closestMatch, isClose := findClosestMatch(match[1], []string{expectedPattern}, threshold)
        if isClose {
            // If the first part is close to 'some text', add the second part to valid matches
            validMatches = append(validMatches, strings.TrimSpace(closestMatch))
        }
    }

    return validMatches
}

func main() {
    text := "This is a sample text with s0me text MY_VALUE, some otner text."
    threshold := 10 

    matches := findMatches(text, threshold)
    fmt.Println("Matches found:", matches)
}
```

The regex pattern `(?i)(some\s*\w*\s*text\s*)([^,]+)` is used to capture phrases that are similar to "some text" followed by any characters until a comma